# How to enable nvm in steps in circleci 2.0?

Tags: npm, circleci, nvm

Here are my steps  in my

```
steps:
  -run:
      name: Setup nvm and npm
      command: |
        wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash
        export NVM_DIR=$HOME/.nvm
        source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh
        nvm install 8.9 && nvm alias default 8.9
   -run: npm install && npm run lint && npm test
```

The second step always fails with this error message

```
/bin/bash: npm: command not found
```

I checked  `.bashrc` and I can see the following lines are added to the end of the file

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Circleci 2.0 invokes the step command by starting a new shell with  `#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail`

If I starts a docker (`docker run -i -t buildpack-deps:xenial`) and apply the first step, and then start a new shell via `#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail`, I can see `npm` is available on the path

I am using docker for this project

```
version: 2
jobs:
  test_main:
    docker:
      - image: buildpack-deps:xenial
```

So why does it fail in circleci 2.0 environment? How can I ensure `npm` will be available to step 2 from step 1?

I have tried to add `[ -s "$HOME/.bashrc" ] && \. "$HOME/.bashrc"` to `~/.bash_profile` (in case `.bashrc` is not executed due to the non-interactive/non-login shell)

To reproduce the issue you can run `circleci build` with this `.circleci/config.yml` file

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: buildpack-deps:xenial
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Setup nvm and npm
          command: |
            wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash
            # Activate nvm
            export NVM_DIR=$HOME/.nvm
            touch $HOME/.nvmrc
            source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh
            # Use node 8.9
            nvm install 8.9 && nvm alias default 8.9
            echo 8.9 > $HOME/.nvmrc
            # Enable nvm in following steps
            echo '[ -s "$HOME/.bashrc" ] && \. "$HOME/.bashrc"' >> $HOME/.bash_profile
            # To fix npm install : "node-pre-gyp: Permission denied"
            npm config set user 0
            npm config set unsafe-perm true
            npm install -g npx webpack webpack-cli jest
            node --version
            npm --version
      - run: npm install
```

You will see the following error message:

```
====>> npm install
  #!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
npm install
/bin/bash: npm: command not found
Error: Exited with code 127
Step failed
Task failed
```

Comment: More of your config would be helpful. For example, what executor and image are you using?

Comment: I am using docker. I added some more info to the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem lies with these lines:

```
        # Enable nvm in following steps
        echo '[ -s "$HOME/.bashrc" ] && \. "$HOME/.bashrc"' >> $HOME/.bash_profile
```

I was hoping to source `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile`. However since the shell of circleci is non-interactive, the environment variable `PS1` is blank. Hence `.bashrc` basically quits immediately once it is sourced, because of this line in `.bashrc`

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

I have to put the following lines directly in the file specified by `$BASH_ENV`

```
echo 'export NVM_DIR=$HOME/.nvm' >> $BASH_ENV
echo 'source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh' >> $BASH_ENV
```

Comment: Didn't worked for me, I had to do `nvm install 8.9 && nvm alias default 8.9` on each step.

Comment: Have anyone found a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I found that changing default node by nvm is not working for my steps.

Solved by:

```
      - run:
          name: 'Install Project Node'
          command: |
            set +x
            source ~/.bashrc

            nvm install 12
            NODE_DIR=$(dirname $(which node))
            echo "export PATH=$NODE_DIR:\$PATH" >> $BASH_ENV
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `source /opt/circleci/.nvm/nvm.sh` in the beginning of every step.